# Analysing grade distributions: difference in proportions across years

Tags: categorical-data, proportion

I have data on grades obtained in a course over three consecutive years. The grade distribution includes the number of students who received a fail, pass, credit, distinction and high distinction.

I need to work out if the proportion of students who obtain a pass (or fail, credit, etc.) is the same, or different across the three cohorts. How can I do this? What type of test should I use?

Comment: Hi @Bunya, welcome to CV. Could you give a little bit more detail in your question? An example of your dataset could help.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks! The data set includes data collected over three consecutive years. Each year data was collected on the grades achieved for one course.  The grade distribution includes the number of students who received a fail, pass, credit, distinction and high distinction.  I need to work out if the proportion of students who obtain a pass (for example) is the same, or different across the three cohorts.

Comment: I edited your question to reflect this new information.

Answer (score 0):

Bunya, I know this is a really old question, and probably solved by now, but can you confirm what you ended up using?

I am working on a similar problem and I think the best solution is to use a Kruskal-Wallis test; it can compare % of grade outcomes one at at time between years. You might also try a multi-factor test that can look for sig. diffs between groups in multiple years. A repeated measure test (like Friendman's) lets you compare one group over multiple years.
I'm no statistician, but this is what I've come across in my own research.